# How to procure moving average on data while keeping 'NaN' values in mind?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data which can contain NaN values and I want to calculate the rolling mean but it should ignore the NaN values.

```
Date        Price
01-03-2020 100.0
02-03-2020 200.0
03-03-2020  NaN
04-03-2020  NaN
05-03-2020  NaN
06-03-2020  NaN
07-03-2020  NaN
08-03-2020  100.0
09-03-2020  300.0
10-03-2020  NaN
```

After `df.rolling(3,on='Date').mean()`
I am getting output

```
    Date        Price
    01-03-2020  NaN
    02-03-2020  NaN
    03-03-2020  NaN
    04-03-2020  NaN
    05-03-2020  NaN
    06-03-2020  NaN
    07-03-2020  NaN
    08-03-2020  NaN
    09-03-2020  NaN
    10-03-2020  NaN
```

The output I want:

```
    Date        Price
    03-03-2020  150.0
    04-03-2020  200.0
    05-03-2020  NaN
    06-03-2020  NaN
    07-03-2020  NaN
    08-03-2020  100.0
    09-03-2020  200.0
    10-03-2020  200.0
```

Comment: So deleted solution not working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688300/calculating-rolling-mean-when-data-contains-nan-values ?

Comment: That question was marked as a duplicate, and so it is removed. Could you please answer here?

Comment: I didn't create a new account. Actually me and my colleague, both are working on this same question. He was not able to post the question, that's why I did it.

Comment: Ok, then I hope got some solution here.

Comment: Please post the solution, if you have any..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.nanmean()`

```
df.rolling(3,on='Date').apply(lambda x : np.nanmean(x))
```

Comment: Through this solution, I am not able to get the exact expected solution provided in the question